# Maven: No suitable driver found for jdbc::mysql://google

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect my Java Maven project (which runs on a Jetty server) to a Google Cloud MySQL Database with the following code:

```
private static final String CREDENTIALS_STRING = "jdbc::mysql://google/weatherplanning?cloudSqlInstance=csci310-project-2:us-central1:myinstance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=xxxx&password=xxxx";
try {
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CREDENTIALS_STRING);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've included both of these dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm getting

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc::mysql://google...

and I don't know what to do. I assume the dependencies should handle adding the JDBC driver to my classpath.

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `jdbc:mysql://....` that is one colon, not two colons between `jdbc` and `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks like you have a typo in your JDBC url. Your URL should start with `jdbc:mysql` instead of `jdbc::mysql`.

Additionally, [you should always use a connection pool](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections) (like [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)). Connection pools have many benefits, including better error handling, exponential backoff, and reduced latency.

You can view Hikari being used with the Cloud SQL JDBC socket factory in the [context of a web application in this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/40b452eff37f9a3b6a3c3e62884d14e96b40f55e/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectionPoolContextListener.java#L49). [Full instructions for deploying it are in the sample's README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/mysql/servlet).